# Attach a modal window to a button and wait for the modal window to close before continue with the button action

Tags: javascript, typescript, simplemodal

I have attached a modal window to a button. I want when the button is clicked the modal window to open with a message . When the modal window is closed continue with the button action ( opening a new frame ) . At the moment I see the modal window for few seconds , then the button click opens a new frame and my modal disappears .

here is my code : 
 My modal window css + html

```
    <style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: visible; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


</style>


<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

My JS pseudo code:

```
.....
let popUpInstruction = require("!text-loader!./Instructions.html");
let editButton = frame.contents().find('input[name$="edit"]'); // just for testing bound it to the Edit button
....
if ( someStatement) {

let place = frame.contents().find(".headerContent");
let popUpInstructionHTML = $($.parseHTML(popUpInstruction));
popUpInstructionHTML.appendTo(place);
let closeButton = popUpInstructionHTML.contents().find(".close")[0];

               editButton.on("click", function () { // just for testing bound it to the Edit button
                        popUpInstructionHTML.show();

//how to make the code to stop here and wait for popUpInstructionHTML to be closed , brefore continue with the editButton action ?


                        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                        $(closeButton).on("click", function() {
                            popUpInstructionHTML.hide();
                        });
                });
}
```

Here is my button :

```
<input value=" Edit " class="btn" name="edit" title="Edit" type="button" onclick="navigateToUrl('url','DETAIL','edit');">
```

Clicking the Edit Button loads another frame and closes my modal window .

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to [trigger custom events](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/). So something like this should work:

```
let closeButton = popUpInstructionHTML.contents().find(".close").first();

editButton.on("click", function () { // just for testing bound it to the Edit button
    popUpInstructionHTML.show();

    // at some point you are going to call:
    // popUpInstructionHTML.trigger("finished");
});

popUpInstructionHTML.on("finished", function(){
    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    $(closeButton).on("click", function() {
        popUpInstructionHTML.hide();
    });
})
```

I don't quite follow why you want to wait for the popup to close before attaching the closeButton click handler... but hopefully you can extract what you need from this answer and modify it to fit your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , unfortunately it doesnt work . The idea is to use the modal window as for example the alert() function works . The alert function will stop and wait for the user to click "OK" and then it will continue. I would like to use the same with a modal window. The main problem is that I'm manipulating a button ( I dont have access to the code and its functionality ) .

Comment: Yes, but you aren't using `alert()` or `input()`. Both of those functions are implemented by the browser and can block all page interactions while waiting for the user. You can't achieve that with a custom popup, so you'll have to break up the function and implement it in two parts.

Comment: Thanks , I have tried your suggestion but I was not able to make it work . I have also tried preventDefault() and return false, but the button keeps executing its onclick action...

Comment: Honestly, I don't fully understand your design, so it's quite possible that my suggestion is flawed... I just took your "`stop here`" comment at face value. You need to think of this as a series of independent steps rather than as a single flow of code. You can't exactly "stop here" in JavaScript... but you *can* do something like "leave this hanging and I'll come back to in response to another event", etc.

Comment: I'm working on a plugin project for a website engine , similar to Facebook. Lets take Facebook for example . I would like to create a Chrome Plugin , when installed it will produce a modal window when I click in the , lets say the Messenger Button. In few words , I install the plugin -> I click on the Messenger Button -> Messenger load is suspended -> A modal window appears -> I close the modal window -> messenger load is resumed.